# When modular tensor categories are equivalent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, abelian-categories, monoidal-categories

I would like to know when we say that two modular tensor categories are equivalent.

Is it true that two modular tensor categories are equivalent if they are equivalent as monoidal categories? Or do we require more conditions?

Answer (score 0):

No, we need to preserve more structure than just the monoidal equivalence. Namely, we want to preserve

- Monoidal structure
- Braiding
- Linear structure
- Twist

Of course, linearity is often assumed a-priori in all functors, so I'll assume it for everything in the following discussion.

Given two MTCs $\mathscr{C}$, $\mathscr{D}$ , we define a ribbon functor between $F:\mathscr{C}\to\mathscr{D}$ to be a braided monoidal functor for which $F(\theta_{C;A})=\theta_{D;F(A)}$ for all $A\in\mathscr{C}$, where $\theta_{\mathscr{C}},\theta_{\mathscr{D}}$ are the twists on $\mathscr{C}$ and $\mathscr{D}$ respectively.

We say that $\mathscr{C}$ and $\mathscr{D}$ are equivalent when there are pairs of ribbon functors between them, such that the composition in ether direction is monoidally naturally equivalent to the identity (note the lack of extra conditions on the natural equivalence).